# How to docker compose to run azure container instance

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file with multiple services like prometheus, grafana, spring boot ms and elk. I am able to start containers on my local machine. But after modifying the file to deploy to azure container instance its failing with errors like:

```
service "prometheus" refers to undefined volume fsefileshare: invalid compose project
```

```
error looking up volume plugin azure_file: plugin "azure_file" not found
```

> Sample docker compose to run in local

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  setup:
    build:
      context: ./config/setup/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
    init: true
    volumes:
      - setup:/state:Z
    environment:
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD:-}
      LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
      KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD: ${KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD:-}
    networks:
      - fse_net

  database_mysql:
      image: mysql:8.0
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
        - ./fse_auth.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/fse_auth.sql:ro
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        
      networks:
        - fse_net
  #************Mongo DB - 1***************
  database_mongo:
    restart: always
    container_name: database_mongo
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db
      - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - fse_net
  #************prometheus***************  
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    depends_on:
      - database_mongo
      - registery
      - company
      - stock
      - gateway
    networks:
      - fse_net
  #************company***************
  company:
    container_name: company
    restart: always
    environment:
      - EUREKA_REGISTERY=registery
      - DATABASE_HOST=database_mongo
    build:
      context: ./company
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    depends_on:
      - database_mongo
      - database_mysql
    networks:
      - fse_net
  #************stock***************
  stock:
    container_name: stock
    environment:
      - EUREKA_REGISTERY=registery
      - DATABASE_HOST=database_mongo
    build:
      context: ./stock
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - database_mongo
    networks:
      - fse_net
  
volumes:
  setup:
  mysql_data:
  mongo_data:
  grafana-storage:
  zookeeper_data:
  zookeeper_log:
  kafka_data:
  elasticsearch:
networks:
  fse_net:
    driver: bridge
```

> Docker compose after modification for azure

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  setup:
    build:
      context: ./config/setup/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
    image: myazureacr.azurecr.io/setup
    init: true
    volumes:
      - setup:/state:Z
    environment:
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD:-}
      LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
      KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD: ${KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD:-}
    networks:
      - fse_net

  database_mysql:
      image: mysql:8.0
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - fse_data:/var/lib/mysql
        - fsefileshare/fse_auth.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/fse_auth.sql:ro
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        
      networks:
        - fse_net

  #************Mongo DB - 1***************
  database_mongo:
    restart: always
    container_name: database_mongo
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - fse_data:/data/db
      - fsefileshare/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - fse_net
  
  #************prometheus***************  
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    container_name: prometheus
    # environment:
    #   - APP_GATEWAY=gateway
    #   - REGISTERY_APP=registery
    volumes:
      - fsefileshare/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    depends_on:
      - database_mongo
      - company
      - stock
    networks:
      - fse_net
  
  #************company***************
  company:
    container_name: company
    restart: always
    environment:
      - EUREKA_REGISTERY=registery
      - DATABASE_HOST=database_mongo
    build:
      context: ./company
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: myazureacr.azurecr.io/company
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    depends_on:
      - database_mongo
      - database_mysql
    networks:
      - fse_net
  #************stock***************
  stock:
    container_name: stock
    environment:
      - EUREKA_REGISTERY=registery
      - DATABASE_HOST=database_mongo
    build:
      context: ./stock
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: myazureacr.azurecr.io/stock
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - database_mongo
   
    networks:
      - fse_net
  
  

volumes:
  fse_data:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: fsefileshare
      storage_account_name: fsestorageaccount
  
networks:
  fse_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: There's no such service as "azure container". Do you mean Azure Container Instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your YAML looks wrong. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-reference-yaml), this is how you should define the volume:

```
volumes: # Array of volumes available to the instances
- name: string
  azureFile:
    shareName: string
    readOnly: boolean
    storageAccountName: string
    storageAccountKey: string
```